# Flutter iOS Firebase Phone-Auth - how to disable reCapcha?

Tags: ios, firebase, authentication, flutter

I'm facing issue with Firebase auth. I got it completely working on Android and iOS. However, for iOS I always receive reCAPCHA screen. On simulator, real device, production or dev env.

I tried this [Firebase Phone Authentication pops up a reCAPTCHA verification window on iOS even if Background Modes and Push Notifications are enabled.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814468/firebase-phone-authentication-pops-up-a-recaptcha-verification-window-on-ios-eve) but it didn't work. xCode log bellow:

```
2019-10-05 13:57:02.393897+0800 Runner[81028:20912038]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2019-10-05 13:57:02.563013+0800 Runner[81028:20911043] Configuring the default Firebase app...
2019-10-05 13:57:02.601937+0800 Runner[81028:20911043] Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
2019-10-05 13:57:02.630720+0800 Runner[81028:20912107] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:56400/6aCv5d5WwnE=/
2019-10-05 13:57:03.791158+0800 Runner[81028:20912038] 6.8.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist.
2019-10-05 13:57:03.794979+0800 Runner[81028:20912038] 6.8.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60101000 started
2019-10-05 13:57:03.795631+0800 Runner[81028:20912038] 6.8.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev3ec8a1cb4)
2019-10-05 13:57:16.131876+0800 Runner[81028:20911043] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7CA7D2A4-DD23-415A-AC76-3A3872EAEB92/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-10-05 13:57:16.132409+0800 Runner[81028:20911043] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2019-10-05 13:57:16.178859+0800 Runner[81028:20911043] Can't find keyplane that supports type 5 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-PhonePad; using 20698_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Complex-Pad_Default
2019-10-05 13:57:21.049877+0800 Runner[81028:20914032] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fbe1c032980] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-10-05 13:57:21.050044+0800 Runner[81028:20914032] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fbe1c032980] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-10-05 13:57:21.050921+0800 Runner[81028:20914032] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-10-05 13:57:21.051010+0800 Runner[81028:20914032] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-10-05 13:57:21.261532+0800 Runner[81028:20912062] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fbe1c50a9a0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-10-05 13:57:21.262593+0800 Runner[81028:20912062] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fbe1c50a9a0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-10-05 13:57:21.265189+0800 Runner[81028:20912062] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-10-05 13:57:21.265504+0800 Runner[81028:20912062] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-10-05 13:57:26.777766+0800 Runner[81028:20912072] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7fbe19e08a10] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-10-05 13:57:26.777947+0800 Runner[81028:20912072] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7fbe19e08a10] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-10-05 13:57:26.778815+0800 Runner[81028:20912072] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2019-10-05 13:57:26.778939+0800 Runner[81028:20912072] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2019-10-05 13:57:28.028051+0800 Runner[81028:20914609] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x7fbe1c50aa70] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-10-05 13:57:28.028242+0800 Runner[81028:20914609] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x7fbe1c50aa70] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-10-05 13:57:28.029358+0800 Runner[81028:20914609] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
2019-10-05 13:57:28.029559+0800 Runner[81028:20914609] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView layer]
PID: 81028, TID: 20912082, Thread name: io.flutter.1.gpu, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   Flutter                             0x000000010c35c790 -[FlutterView createSurfaceWithResourceGLContext:] + 50
5   Flutter                             0x000000010c36b976 _ZNK7flutter15PlatformViewIOS16CreateIOSSurfaceEv + 166
6   Flutter                             0x000000010c36be3b _ZN7flutter15PlatformViewIOS22CreateRenderingSurfaceEv + 43
7   Flutter                             0x000000010c3bab07 _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7flutter12PlatformView13NotifyCreatedEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS4_EEFvvEEclEv + 31
8   Flutter                             0x000000010c37aa7f _ZN3fml15MessageLoopImpl10FlushTasksENS_9FlushTypeE + 117
9   Flutter                             0x000000010c37f9e8 _ZN3fml17MessageLoopDarwin11OnTimerFireEP16__CFRunLoopTimerPS0_ + 26
10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fad13e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fad0ff2 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fad085a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010facaefc __CFRunLoopRun + 2220
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010faca302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
15  Flutter                             0x000000010c37fb13 _ZN3fml17MessageLoopDarwin3RunEv + 65
16  Flutter                             0x000000010c37a9c4 _ZN3fml15MessageLoopImpl5DoRunEv + 22
17  Flutter                             0x000000010c37f026 _ZNSt3__114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEZN3fml6ThreadC1ERKNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEE3$_0EEEEEPvSJ_ + 170
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011207f2eb _pthread_body + 126
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000112082249 _pthread_start + 66
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011207e40d thread_start + 13
2019-10-05 13:57:34.405862+0800 Runner[81028:20912082] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView layer]
PID: 81028, TID: 20912082, Thread name: io.flutter.1.gpu, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   Flutter                             0x000000010c35c790 -[FlutterView createSurfaceWithResourceGLContext:] + 50
5   Flutter                             0x000000010c36b976 _ZNK7flutter15PlatformViewIOS16CreateIOSSurfaceEv + 166
6   Flutter                             0x000000010c36be3b _ZN7flutter15PlatformViewIOS22CreateRenderingSurfaceEv + 43
7   Flutter                             0x000000010c3bab07 _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7flutter12PlatformView13NotifyCreatedEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS4_EEFvvEEclEv + 31
8   Flutter                             0x000000010c37aa7f _ZN3fml15MessageLoopImpl10FlushTasksENS_9FlushTypeE + 117
9   Flutter                             0x000000010c37f9e8 _ZN3fml17MessageLoopDarwin11OnTimerFireEP16__CFRunLoopTimerPS0_ + 26
10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fad13e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fad0ff2 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fad085a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010facaefc __CFRunLoopRun + 2220
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010faca302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
15  Flutter                             0x000000010c37fb13 _ZN3fml17MessageLoopDarwin3RunEv + 65
16  Flutter                             0x000000010c37a9c4 _ZN3fml15MessageLoopImpl5DoRunEv + 22
17  Flutter                             0x000000010c37f026 _ZNSt3__114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEZN3fml6ThreadC1ERKNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEE3$_0EEEEEPvSJ_ + 170
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011207f2eb _pthread_body + 126
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000112082249 _pthread_start + 66
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011207e40d thread_start + 13
2019-10-05 13:57:35.160309+0800 Runner[81028:20911043] [Common] _BSMachError: port 8007; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2019-10-05 13:57:36.052924+0800 Runner[81028:20914610] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C6.1:2][0x7fbe1c01eac0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-10-05 13:57:36.053084+0800 Runner[81028:20914610] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C6.1:2][0x7fbe1c01eac0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-10-05 13:57:36.053971+0800 Runner[81028:20914610] TIC Read Status [6:0x0]: 1:57
2019-10-05 13:57:36.054140+0800 Runner[81028:20914610] TIC Read Status [6:0x0]: 1:57
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: It was long time ago - I think I found workaround for it. Not sure if this issue is around still, as within nearly 1 year, Flutter got massive changes.