# How to disable reCAPTCHA verification for firebase authentication on iOS?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am working on a flutter app which has a registration flow like this.

- The user selects their Google/Apple id depending on the device
- Then they enter their phone number to get an SMS
- Then they enter the SMS code to verify it
- Then they enter their personal info and enter into the app

This is the flow on Android but on iOS after entering the phone number the in-app browser open a link for a reCAPTCHA verification. I want to disable it as it results in bad user experience.

So, after looking online I enabled push notification and background mode but I am still getting redirected.

There might be something that I missed but can't find what is it.

Any help would be great. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Use Anonymous Authentication it will skip the reCAPTCHA part: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth .  Using Anonymous Authentication in Web does skip the ReCAPTCHA . I guess it does in mobile too. For flutter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBJoY4VjECo this link has the tutorial for implementing Anonymous Sign In

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that you've enabled "Background Modes", it seems that you need to add the "Remote Notification" checkbox. See also the documentation "[Pushing Background Updates to Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app#overview)"

These SO questions are related to your problem, give it a try.

- [Firebase Phone Authentication pops up a reCAPTCHA verification window on iOS even if Background Modes and Push Notifications are enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814468/firebase-phone-authentication-pops-up-a-recaptcha-verification-window-on-ios-eve)
- [How to disable recaptcha verification in phone Authentication with firebase for IOS Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165708/how-to-disable-recaptcha-verification-in-phone-authentication-with-firebase-for)