# How to disable recaptcha verification in phone Authentication with firebase for IOS Flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-ios

I am working on a flutter app which has a registration flow like this.

-The user selects their Google/Apple id depending on the device
-Then they enter their phone number to get an SMS
-Then they enter the SMS code to verify it
-Then they enter their personal info and enter into the app

This is the flow on Android but on iOS after entering the phone number the in-app browser open `{my_project_name}.firebase-app.com` website. It appears for 2-3 seconds and says that verifying for bot(no google captcha appears). And then it redirects me back to app. I want to disable it as it results in bad user experience.(in real device)

I enabled silent notifications by generating APN's authentication key and uploading it to firebase.

There might be something that I missed but can't find what is it.

Please help me solving this issue and thank you for giving your time.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution.
In Xcode under signing and capabilities, Enable "Background Modes" capability and Inside of the "Background Modes", you have to click "Remote Notifictions" checkbox.
this worked in my case

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for this for weeks man.

Comment: @Miki this solution is not working for me