# Disable Re-Captcha in Firebase Phone Auth Flutter (2023 issue)

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I want to disable Re-Captcha in Firebase Phone Auth in Flutter.

In other solutions where folks enable the 'Android Device Verification' API in Google Cloud Console and everything is working fine for them, But Currently 'Android Device Verification' API is Removed by Google and merged with 'Google Play Integrity API'.

I already enabled the 'Google Play Integrity API', Plus I added my device SHA1 and SHA-256 both in the Firebase console and add the update google-service.json in the project.

Still, I am getting the Re-Captcha screen.

I added the following libraries in app/build.gradle

[image]

And 'Google Play Integrity API' is also enabled:

[image]

Also, I enabled the 'App Check' in Firebase Console, Added SHA 256 is added.

[image]

Comment: No, not now @NehilKoshiya

Comment: You can  disable app verification by setting true to `appVerificationDisabledForTesting` check this [github](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/discussions/3381#discussioncomment-2829411) also check the suggestions in these stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814468/firebase-phone-authentication-pops-up-a-recaptcha-verification-window-on-ios-eve) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67635629/18265638)

Comment: Already tried but not working @SathiAiswarya

Comment: There is a bug raised for this at [github](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10593) shared by Niladri in below answer you can follow that further updates.

Comment: hi @amit how did you solve this issue, I'm stuck there and I've almost tried every solution I could, I upgraded flutter and all dependencies including firebase_core and firebase_auth but it didn't help so I downgraded them it didn't work either, I enabled Firebase App Check API
Google Play Integrity API 
   implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"  to 1.6.0

Comment: I solved this
- First, check the Firebase cloud console, and check that the key must not be restricted.
- It still does not work then remove the current project from Firebase and recreate it(It will generate an auto key in Firebase cloud console)

- CHECK IN REAL DEVICE ONLY. NOT IN EMULATOR OR SIMULATOR. @Fada

Answer (score 1):

try to activate app check in your firebase console https://firebase.google.com/products/app-check then register you app, this worked for me

Comment: Thanks for your response @Chalwe19,I tried this but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

**LATEST UPDATE:**

[Firebase Github comment](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10593#issuecomment-1515617708)

Assuming you have done everything as per the documentation of AppCheck and PlayIntegrity guidelines and yet you have the ReCaptcha appearing, this information is for you.

In addition, you might have the OTP sms having the label .firebaseapp.com, instead of the actual App name.

`This is an issue on Which Firebase is working currently on priority basis.`

Multiple users like me have reported this to Firebase Github.

[Here is my reported issue.](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10593#issuecomment-1514144738)

Answer (score 0):

Just add SHA-1 & SHA-256 Keys in your Firebase project.

You can add key using below steps:

Open terminal in your IDE and change access android/gradlew signingReport and press enter.

Then you can copy paste both keys from debug section to your firebase project and you will not get Re-Captcha verification.